# Why doesn't my delay happen?

Tags: java, android, handler, delay

currently developing an app where I need to take a number of wifi measurements, take an average of these measurements and store the averages. However I've found that I have to implement a delay between measurements otherwise there's not enough time to see any variation between measurements.

In the Handler.postDelayed() method I've tried to implement a 2000ms delay, however when I view the timestamp of the logs generated by TAKEWIFI, there appears to be no delay at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_takewifi);
    final String[] strArr = new String[60];
    for (int i=0;i<60;i++)
    {
        strArr[i] = "EMPTY";
    }
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    final int state = wifi.getWifiState();
    if(state == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED) {
        RawData rD = new RawData();
        Toast.makeText(TakeWifi.this, 
                "Taking RSS measurement, hold still!", 
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        for(int a=0;a<30;a++)
        {
            wifi.startScan();
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
                }
            });
            List<ScanResult> results = wifi.getScanResults();
            String index = (String) results.toString();
            int forCount = 0;
            int ifCount = 0;
            for (String retval: index.split(",")){
                if (((forCount%5==1)||(forCount%5==3))&&(ifCount<60)){
                    strArr[ifCount] = retval;
                    strArr[ifCount] = strArr[ifCount].replace(" BSSID:", "BSSID:");
                    strArr[ifCount] = strArr[ifCount].replace(" level:", "level:");
                    ifCount++;
                }
                forCount++;
            }
            for(int check=0;check<60;check++)
            {
                Log.d("TAKEWIFI","strArr[" + check + "]: " + strArr[check]);
            }
            rD.setStrArr(strArr,rD);
        }
        final String[] temp = rD.getStrArr(rD);
        for(int b=0;b<20;b++)
        {
            strArr[b]=temp[b];
        }
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        {Log.d("STRARR",strArr[i]);}
        List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(temp);
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            Log.d("STRLIST",stringList.get(i));
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringList);
        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        if (listview==null)
        {
        Log.d("LISTVIEW","NULL");
        }listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        Toast.makeText(TakeWifi.this,"RSS measurement complete",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(TakeWifi.this,"Wifi Not Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    final Button commitBut=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    commitBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override     
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(state == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED){
            commit(strArr);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(TakeWifi.this,"Wifi Not Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why do you call `handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);` inside `run()`? The run function does not do anything except for calling itself after 2000 milliseconds. Is that what you intend to do?

Answer (score 2):

Replace your handle with this and put everything you want delayed into it.

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Everything you want to be delayed needs to go inside this runnable
        }
    }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are waiting in another thread (hence the run() method in your handler) :) Try removing that whole handler magic and call Thread.sleep directly.